# Subsonic - Active Records doesn't grab all my tables

Tags: c#, sql-server, orm, subsonic

I have a real simple database with 8 tables:

- Activities
- Classes
- Companies
- Computers
- Customers
- Services
- Users
- Vendors

but whenever I include the TT files for Subsonic, it seems to only create classes for two of my tables, Classes and Customers.

What is the reason for this, and how can I fix it?

Config for SubSonic:

```
const string Namespace = "SimpleTimerDatabase.Data";
const string ConnectionStringName = "SimpleTimerDatabase.Properties.Settings.QTimerConnectionString";

//This is the name of your database and is used in naming
//the repository. By default we set it to the connection string name
const string DatabaseName = "QTimer";
```

And my connection Strings:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="SimpleTimerDatabase.Properties.Settings.QTimerConnectionString"
        connectionString="Data Source=THESTUDIO\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=QTimer;Integrated Security=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subsonic doesn't do any checking of column names, so when I had a column titled "class" and another titled "1099", the autogenerated code couldn't compile because those are invalid identifiers.

Comment: SubSonic 2.2 does do this checking, but for 3.x you'd need to look at using a different TT template that might handle this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Are there differences in the tables? Do the Classes and Customers table have a primary key configured where the others don't?

Comment: Classes does not have a PK, Customers does.

Comment: How about an identity column?

Comment: Both tables have an identity column, but so do the other tables.

Comment: I found the problem, sense I have a table, Class, there are some column names called 'class' so when SubSonic tries to define that column, there is a syntax error.